# Aggregating data with dates and factor variable

Tags: r

I have a long format table with three variables; id, dates, and a factor variable.

```
dates <- (seq.Date(from = as.Date(c("2015-02-01")), 
                   to = as.Date(c("2016-01-01")), 
                   by = "month") - 1)

data <- data.frame("date" = rep(dates, 2), 
                    "id" = rep(c(1, 2), each = 12), 
                   "grade" = c(rep("Z", 4), rep("T", 3), rep("R", 5), 
                               rep("T", 2), rep("R", 3), rep("T", 7)))
```

What I would like to get is such a table

```
id     start date    fin date      grade
1      2015-01-31    2015-04-30      Z
1      2015-05-31    2015-07-31      T
1      2015-08-31    2015-12-31      R
2      2015-01-31    2015-02-28      T
2      2015-03-31    2015-05-31      R
2      2015-06-30    2015-12-31      T
```

I tried the code below with dplry package as well as with basic R functions but none of the attempts produces what I would like.

```
1st attempt

data %>% group_by(id, grade) %>% 
        summarize(Min_val = min(date), Max_val = max(date)) 

2nd attempt

first <- with(data, by(data,  list(id, grade), head, n=1))
last <- with(data, by(data,  list(id, grade), tail, n=1))

highestd <- do.call("rbind", as.list(first))
lowestd <- do.call("rbind", as.list(last))

data.f <- cbind(highestd[, c("id", "date")], lowestd[, c("date", "grade")])
colnames(data.f) <- c("id", "start.date", "fin.date", "grade")
data.f <- data.f[order(data.f$id, data.f$start.date),]
data.f
```

Comment: The only difference I'm seeing between your first attempt and your desired output is the order of the rows. `summarize` returns the data ordered by the grouping variables. You have `grade` as a factor with levels in alphabetical order, so that's what you got back. If you want to change the order, just change the order of the factor levels

Answer (score 1):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
data %>%
 group_by(id, grade, rleid = with(rle(grade), rep(seq_along(lengths), lengths))) %>%
 summarise(start_date = min(date),
        fin_date = max(date)) %>%
 arrange(rleid) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid)

     id grade start_date fin_date  
  <dbl> <chr> <date>     <date>    
1     1 Z     2015-01-31 2015-04-30
2     1 T     2015-05-31 2015-07-31
3     1 R     2015-08-31 2015-12-31
4     2 T     2015-01-31 2015-02-28
5     2 R     2015-03-31 2015-05-31
6     2 T     2015-06-30 2015-12-31
```

It just creates a run-length type group ID around "grade" column.

The same with `rleid()` from `data.table`:

```
data %>%
 group_by(id, grade, rleid = rleid(grade)) %>%
 summarise(start_date = min(date),
        fin_date = max(date)) %>%
 arrange(rleid) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-rleid)
```